# How to add dynamically precreate group of views?

Tags: android

I want to dynamically add groups of views. Can I precreate this in XML and then add it by its ID? I want to add something like that:https://i.stack.imgur.com/8nRuM.png

Comment: Look for ViewStub. Can be helpful in your context

Comment: Thanks, that's 100% what I need. Can you write this in answer, so I can mark it as good answer?

Comment: Where do you want the add the views. Your question is a bit ambiguous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look for **ViewStub**. Can be helpful in your context